# Identify Folder and File using REGEX for URL ReWrite

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewrite-module

I have a number of URLs that look like the one below and I am trying to develop a REGEX to capture the second instance of /ORGNAME/ and everything after until the end of the .aspx. "/ORGNAME/About-Us/About-Us.aspx" to be exact. Is this something that can be done in REGEX? I am a complete REGEX n00b so any guidance would be helpful. Thanks!

https://www.domain.org/ORGNAME/Membership/About-Org-Membership/ORGNAME/About-Us/About-Us.aspx

Comment: Like this one: `ORGNAME(?=(?:\/[\w-]*?){2}[^\/]*$)` ? (https://regex101.com/r/hQ0dK3/1)

Comment: Close, but I need the preceeding "/" and everything to the end of the file extension. This seems to just match the second instance of ORGNAME

Comment: ORGNAME(?=(?:\/[\w-]*?){2}[^\/]*$)(.*) Gets me everything after so I just need to get the preceeding "/" now

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to match the `/` before the 2nd instance of `ORGNAME` and everything to the end:

```
(\/ORGNAME(?:\/[\w-]*?){2}[^\/]*$)
```

The first captured group contains `/ORGNAME/About-Us/About-Us.aspx`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hQ0dK3/2).

Comment: Seems to work, but IIS ReWrite is not able to match the pattern. Is there a way to get this into a capture group?

Comment: I think you want to match the whole input string, right? Then, try `^(.*?)(\/ORGNAME(?:\/[\w-]*?){2}[^\/]*$)`.